# Android: Call method from another activity kotlin not work

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to call a method from another activity.

I'm trying to do this but it does not work:

```
(applicationContext as MainActivity).getAllGroupFromTheDatabaseToList()
```

Error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.emoonadev.futurfit.MainActivity
```

I do not want the method to be static, so no companion object

Comment: that is obviously because `applicationContext` is not a `MainActivity`. It is even called a **application**context

Comment: applicationContext  should be your mainActivity context.

Comment: So why in java is work ? ((MainActivity) context).refreshList();

Comment: In my other application in java is work fine

Comment: that's probably because you use it differrntly.

Comment: Application context and activity context are not the same.

Comment: Also using database inside activity seems like a bad architectural decision. Handle databse operations in different classes and follow Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: These are two activities that use the same database, I do not want to rewrite the function in the second activity.
I have always been told never to rewrite the same function twice in programming.

Comment: Then you could implement a base-class or a utility-class handling the databases for you. You should not repeat yourself, but you have to consider other principals as well.

Answer (score 2):

The `applicationContext` as the name states is not `Activity` at all thus the cast fails.

Regardless of this you should reconsider what you're trying to do. Another activity might not even exist while you're in the activity doing things.

Instead consider implementing a store you can *inject* to both of the activities and observe changes as necessary.

Default *Android* components you could use for this are bound services or if you want to go back anyway use `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: No, when I want to call the method I'm sure the activity is already created! What is the solution then? The best way to do this?

Comment: Not using dependency injection or similar approaches, try to implement a [Bound Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html). The activity might have been removed by the system already, so never assume there's one which is not in foreground.

Comment: I do not want to use onActivityResult, because it is only used if in the second activity I do finish (). And the problem is that I do not want to finish ()

Answer (score 0):

Try it out

```
class DataForm : Fragment() {
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Tasks(this).getData()
    }
    override fun getResponse(String response) {
        // code
    }
}

class Tasks(private val context: Any) {
    fun getData() {

        val getContext = (context as DataForm).activity
        val getFragment = (context as DataForm)

        val responseListener = Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            getFragment.getResponse(response)
        }

        val errorListener = Response.ErrorListener { error ->
            error.printStackTrace();
        }

        val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, responseListener, errorListener)
        Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext).add(stringRequest)
    }
}
```